# Should we keep [kartik-v] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There is a tag [kartik-v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kartik-v). And there are 59 questions with this tag.
They are about yii2-widget-fileinput, not the person who keeps it running.

Comment: That's hilarious. People are actually saying "I'm using kartik-v" like they think that's the name of the project. Wow. (Or they could be saying they're literally using the person, which... OK let's not go there.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tag doesn't add anything to questions, so I think there's no reason to keep it.

There are only 60 questions tagged, so we can just retag these question manually and this tag will be deleted by system.

Edit: there's also tag [kartik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kartik).

Comment: Or we could just merge the tag into yii2 to save editing if feasible?

Comment: I've merged kartik-v and kartik into yii2 - between the two of them, only 3 occurrences of yii2 was added to a question where it wasn't already present.

Comment: @JonClements I'm not particularly familiar with the libraries, but it seems that this is a set of unofficial additions to Yii 2.

Comment: @Stijn apart from three occurrences they're tagged/mentioned where appropriate in the Qs anyway... seems a bit niche and weird to have as an undocumented tag (especially spread over two tags).